# Sum column values by a cut off date

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame which is originally a data series with multiple columns such as date:

```
         date         score 
0     2020-01-5         0
1     2020-02-10        1
2     2020-02-19        1
3     2020-03-17        0 
4     2020-03-20        1
.        .              .
.        .              .
```

I want to sum the values in the score column by the cutoff date of 2020-02-19 meaning before and after it.

So I will have an output like this:

```
before_cutoff= 1
after_cutoff= --
```

my code is something like this and I think groupby doesn't accept datetime as an attribute

```py
before_cutoff=df_copy.gropuby('score')['date'< 2020-02-19].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

If you just want to split before/after:

```
group = np.where(df['date'].lt('2020-02-19'), 'before', 'after')
df.groupby(group)['score'].sum()
```

Or:

```
mask = df['date'].lt('2020-02-19')

pd.Series({'before': df.loc[mask, 'score'].sum(),
           'after':  df.loc[~mask, 'score'].sum(),
          })
```

Output:

```
after     2
before    1
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

---

###### original answer

Set up an additional grouper:

```
import numpy as np

group = np.where(df['date'].lt('2020-02-19'), 'before', 'after')

out = df.groupby(['date', group])['score'].sum()
```

Output:

```
date              
2020-01-5   before    0
2020-02-10  before    1
2020-02-19  after     1
2020-03-17  after     0
2020-03-20  after     1
Name: score, dtype: int64
```

Wide format:

```
out = df.groupby(['date', group])['score'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
            after  before
date                     
2020-01-5       0       0
2020-02-10      0       1
2020-02-19      1       0
2020-03-17      0       0
2020-03-20      1       0
```

Or with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
out = (pd.crosstab(df['date'], group, aggfunc='sum', values=df['score'])
         .rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
            after  before
date                     
2020-01-5     NaN     0.0
2020-02-10    NaN     1.0
2020-02-19    1.0     NaN
2020-03-17    0.0     NaN
2020-03-20    1.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.Much appreciate it. I actually want just the summation of the values before and after the specific  date. So I can divide them by the total sum of the column and have a ratio of each group.

Comment: @Amirtak can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Comment: @Amirtak or did you just want `df.groupby(group)['score'].sum()`?

Comment: The latter. Just the sum without creating a new grouper.( if it's possible)

Comment: You can compute the sum in two steps, but you have to compute the grouper anyway

Comment: Thank you again. Let me test it, I will post the result.

Comment: See update for another method

Comment: To clarify a further I want a piece of code that sums the values before the date as one output and same thing for the after the date. So I would have two float output showing two numbers and usable to calculate the ratio calculation. E.g.:
                           score
before_date=       35

Comment: It works. And thank you. I just wanted to have each part of after and before in a separate float variable.